# Absolute position relative which parent in tables? (IE6 vs Firefox/Chrome)

Tags: html-table, position, parent, internet-explorer-6, absolute

I have a piece of code that do as I want in IE6 but not in Chrome/Firefox:

In IE6, the img is displayed with absolute position relative the td, as I wanted/expected. In Firefix/Chrome the img is displayed relative the outer div.

```
<div>
      <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="rel cell">
                    <img src="style/easypos_mobile/icons/pencil.png" class="icon" onclick="_onclick.newArticle_andraNr();"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
     </table>
</div>

.rel
{
    position: relative;
}

.icon
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: -23px;
}

.cell
{
    width: 186px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this stuff:

> The specs leave it open to the
>   User-Agent to decide if a table-cell
>   can act as a container for absolute
>   positioned objects.
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position
>   (note the 'effect of
>   'position:relative' on
>   table-row-group, table-  header-group,
>   table-footer-group, table-row,
>   table-column-group,   table-column,
>   table-cell, and table-caption elements
>   is undefined').

This fixed it:

```
<table><tr>
   <td style="position: relative; width: 180px;">
     <div style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;">
       <img src="imageA.gif" class="status">
       <img src="imageB.gif" class="status">
     </div>
  </td>
</tr></table>
```